# List of all scheduled tasks using Python in AWS server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have an AWS server in which i have a list of scheduled tasks. When i am executing below python script saved in a file named `script.py` through command prompt, i am not getting name of many tasks in the console.

**script**

```
import win32com.client
def Task_Names():
    path = find_path()
    columns1 = ['Workflow Name','Last Run Time','Status']
    dat = pd.DataFrame(columns1)
    TASK_STATE = {0: 'Unknown',
                  1: 'Disabled',
                  2: 'Queued',
                  3: 'Ready',
                  4: 'Running'}
    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
    scheduler.Connect()
    folders = [scheduler.GetFolder('\\')]
    while folders:
        folder = folders.pop(0)
        folders += list(folder.GetFolders(0))

        for task in folder.GetTasks(0):
            if task.LastTaskResult == -2147023829:
                result = 'Failed'
            elif task.LastTaskResult == -2147024894:
                result = 'The system cannot find the file specified'
            elif task.LastTaskResult == 267009:
                result = 'The task is currently running'
            elif task.LastTaskResult == 0:
                result = 'Completed'
            #status.append(valu)
            print(task.Name,task.LastRunTime,result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Task_Names()
```

I saved the file in `H:\ScriptRepo`, so i am navigating to the folder by using cd command `cd /d H:\ScriptRepo` in the command prompt. Once i reach there, i am typing `python script.py`

The problem is i am not able to get name of all the scheduled tasks. When i execute the same script in my local PC, i am able to get the name of all scheduled tasks which i see in task scheduler library window. What am i missing? And Why does this script behave differently in AWS and how do i solve it?

Comment: Missing administrative privileges?

Comment: I do have admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Its strange, when i execute the script only list i am getting are the ones i added in the scheduler. Similarly if i ask a different user to execute the script using his credentials it is printing only those tasks which he/she added in the task scheduler. Point to be considered is all the users have administrator privileges.

To solve this i logged into the server using credentials of administrator and now it is printing all workflow details i wanted.